# How to index a numpy 2d array with a 2d array mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

Let's say we have a numpy 2D array like the following:

```
x = array([[0, 7, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4],
           [4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 7, 3]])
```

and a 2D mask like the following:

```
mask = array([[ True, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
              [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

I'm trying to use the mask in order to get the elements for each row.
So the output should look something like this:

```
array(
    [0, 1],
    [2]
)
```

If I use `x[mask]` I get `array([0, 1, 2])` which is wrong because it flattens out all the selected items.

Any ideas to return it as a 2D array?

Comment: These kinds of operations are not well-defined for numpy arrays. I would suggest taking a look at the [Awkward Array](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I'll check it out

Comment: your desired result is not a 2d array!  What do you expect to do with the result?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing elaborates on boolean array indexing.  Since, in general, this kind of indexing does not produce the same number of elements in any one dimension, the result is flat.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm trying to create a generalized version of numpy's intersect1d: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[xi[mi] for xi,mi in zip(x,mask)]
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but I want to avoid doing a `for loop`. I want to do it in a more vectorized way. Thanks!